# Action of fundamental group of the base space on the homology of the fiber

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups, spectral-sequences, fibration

The following was extracted from Hatcher’s book of algebraic topology:

[image: action]

Could you explain me with more detail what is this action of the fundamental group of the base space of a fibration $\pi: E \to B$ on the homology of the fiber $F$, please? Actually, I didn’t understand its definition.

Comment: Do you understand the homotopy equivalence of fibers? Hatcher is defining the action as using the homotopy equivalence to push forward homology classes.

Comment: you can find this in Hatcher chapter 4 on  page 405